# AVUncaughtExceptionHandler when using AVOS cloud login

Tags: android, cloud

I am currently using AVOS cloud with login. But there is a login error whenever i tried to login.
The error shows:

```
E/AVUncaughtExceptionHandler(25353): AVUncaughtExceptionHandler caught a NullPointerException exception 

02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902): com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException: write javaBean error
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JavaBeanSerializer.write(JavaBeanSerializer.java:193)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JSONSerializer.write(JSONSerializer.java:330)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.toJSONString(JSON.java:388)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.avos.avoscloud.AVUser.changeCurrentUser(AVUser.java:108)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.avos.avoscloud.AVUser$2.onSuccess(AVUser.java:387)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.avos.avoscloud.GetHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess(GetHttpResponseHandler.java:87)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:364)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:134)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902): Caused by: com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException: write javaBean error
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JavaBeanSerializer.write(JavaBeanSerializer.java:193)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.MapSerializer.write(MapSerializer.java:130)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.ObjectFieldSerializer.writeProperty(ObjectFieldSerializer.java:111)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JavaBeanSerializer.write(JavaBeanSerializer.java:180)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    ... 15 more
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902): Caused by: com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException: write javaBean error
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JavaBeanSerializer.write(JavaBeanSerializer.java:193)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:96)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.ObjectFieldSerializer.writeProperty(ObjectFieldSerializer.java:116)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JavaBeanSerializer.write(JavaBeanSerializer.java:180)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    ... 18 more
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902): Caused by: com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException: write javaBean error
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JavaBeanSerializer.write(JavaBeanSerializer.java:193)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.ObjectFieldSerializer.writeProperty(ObjectFieldSerializer.java:111)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JavaBeanSerializer.write(JavaBeanSerializer.java:180)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    ... 21 more
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.util.FieldInfo.get(FieldInfo.java:220)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.FieldSerializer.getPropertyValue(FieldSerializer.java:88)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.JavaBeanSerializer.write(JavaBeanSerializer.java:148)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    ... 23 more
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to encode an association with an unsaved AVObject
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.avos.avoscloud.AVRelation.getQuery(AVRelation.java:102)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    at com.avos.avoscloud.AVRelation.getQuery(AVRelation.java:87)
02-28 17:43:42.002: E/AndroidRuntime(26902):    ... 28 more
```

My current avos version is 2.3.2.1 with Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it by deleting the relation column to roles. Appendly, AVOS clouds relation with roles doesn't really works as well (at least for this version - 2.3.2.1 ). This is not the first time I met error for relational tables in AVOS-cloud. I would suggest avoid the relational tables (especially for user-roles relation)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question.
I'm the Android Developer from AVOS Cloud.
I find the root cause of this bug and will update the fix in the next release 2.4.1 in next week.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. :) Hope to hear the updates for the version release soon.